# Is DirectAccess in server 2012 replacement for VPN solution?

Tags: windows, vpn

I have read about some new features for server 2012, and I saw DirectAccess. I am a little bit confused about that.

Is this feature a replacement for VPN solution?
Or can this features be a replacement for a VPN solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's a VPN replacement if your environment matches the DA deployment requirements. The clients must be Windows 7 Enterprise or Ultimate, or Windows 8 Enterprise, and in your domain. You also need to have a Server 2012 DA infrastructure configured properly, which will depend on a few things.